Multiplying differential equation accross by differential forms
In class the teacher wrote the following that I am having trouble accepting.
We have a differential equation
$$\frac{1}{x(s)}\frac{dx(s)}{ds}=f(y)\frac{dy(s)}{ds},$$
which gets rewritten as
$$\frac{d\text{log}(x(s))}{ds}=f(y)\frac{dy(s)}{ds}.$$
They then proceed to multiply across by $ds$ and integrate the left hand side to get
$$\text{log}(x(s))=\int f(y)\frac{dy(s)}{ds} ds=\int f(y)\,dy(s).$$
Can you just do this like this? It seems weird to me that we can just go from something that's a derivative to something that's not by multiplying across by a form.

Do you know the fundamental theorem of calculus?

This is just integrating both sides - really, it's how separation of variables operates (at an informal level).

This question is a duplicate of: Is my explanation of why we can make $\frac{dy}{dx} {dx} = {dy}$ in the separable differential equations valid?.

Yes. Anti-derivatives and derives cancel out. You can verify that by doing it in reverse:
$$\ g(x(s))=\int f(y)\,dy(s)$$
$$\ \frac{d}{ds} g(x(s))= \frac{d}{ds} \int f(y)\,dy(s)$$
By chain rule,
$$\ \frac{dx(s)}{ds} \cdot  \frac{d}{dx(s)} g(x(s))= \frac{dy(s)}{ds} \cdot  \frac{d}{dy(s)} \int f(y)\,dy(s) $$
$$\ g’(x(s)) \frac{dx(s)}{ds} = f(y) \frac{dy(s)}{ds} $$
Take $g(x)=log(x)$, it yields exactly your work in reverse.
The way they “multiply by dx” is actually just a handy way to solve the differential equations.
